# VSTS, Xamarin Forms, Net Standard, Android: project.assets.json not found while I called restore

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, .net-standard

I'm building a `Xamarin Forms` app on vsts (via yml).
Steps are almost identicals for iOS and Android.
The whole solution builds fine on my machine and the iOS phase builds fine on VSTS.

However I get an error on the msbuild of the solution within the Android phase.
The error is:

> [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.104\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(327,5):
>   Error : Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Controls\obj\project.assets.json'
>   not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

I understand that I first have to run `dot net restore` to generate the `project.assets.json` file and I do. Here are my corresponding yml tasks:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Dot Net Restore'
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: |
       MyApp.*/*.csproj
       Platforms/MyApp.Android/*.csproj
       Platforms/MyApp.Controls.Android/*.csproj
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  displayName: 'Building Android'
  inputs:
      solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
      configuration: 'Release'
      buildToolOption: msbuild
```

Note that `MyApp.Controls.Android` has a reference to `MyApp.Controls` (which is a .Net Standard library) and this is that project on which the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet restore task definied in your yml file is not correct, you should use the task **`NuGetCommand@2`** for NuGet restore.

Below is an example for the YAML build file:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Building Android'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    vsVersion: 15.0
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    logProjectEvents: false
```